# Hide/Remove app for a user on Mac

Tags: macos, applications, high-sierra

Is it possible to remove or hide an app for a user on Mac? This way I want to make a user not known about the presence of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

1. Create a folder named "Applications" in your home folder.
2. Move the app from the standard applications folder to the applications folder in your home folder.

This way only you can see and use the app.